# Silverlight app not running on Windows Phone 10

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

We have a **Silverlight** app written for **Windows Phone 8**.

Everyone in the company has upgraded to **Windows Phone 10** and the app still install and runs perfectly from the Microsoft Store. Except for one phone! Unlocking the phone for development and running it in debug gives the following errors in the output...

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Getting the detailed output for the **FileNotFoundException** gives the following...

```
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Windows.RuntimeHost, Version=2.0.6.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The **System.Windows.Runtimehost** dll is the host for running a Silverlight application. That would explain why it does not run. But how can this be missing from the phone and not from any other phone?

We tried a factory reset of the phone and it still does not work.

Anyone else seem this, any ideas?

Comment: Does that phone'model is different  with others?

Comment: which win10mobile build do you use? 14393 or 10586

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a suggestion from a Microsoft forum that worked.

I used the **Windows Device Recovery Tool** that allows a new image to be downloaded and then installed on the phone. It automatically pulls down the correct image for your make/model of phone. I assume these are hosted at Microsoft. After the phone was updated with the new image it worked as expected.

Comment: again you miss all details. Which phone do you use and which version have you flashed?